# How to run netscape navigator with rsh and DISPLAY?

Tags: x11, rsh

I want to launch Netscape Navigator
The 6000 port on my host is open
the host is added using xhost+

```
host + 192.168.0.33
```

If I did

```
rlogin 192.168.0.33
```

and then

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.0.2:0
navigator
```

Works fine.
But I want to run directly on host I have tried

```
rsh 192.168.0.33 DISPLAY=192.168.0.2:0 navigator
```

and

```
 DISPLAY=192.168.0.2:0 192.168.0.33 navigator
```

and

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.0.2:0
rsh 192.168.0.33 /usr/bin/navigator
```

and

```
rsh 192.168.0.33 "export DISPLAY=192.168.0.2:0 ; /usr/bin/navigator"
```

But don't work
Why?

FAQ

Q: Why not ssh which is simpler and more secure?

A: This is an old host, ssh2 is not supported

Q: Why use a very old browser?

A: Is for turn on an old Bare-metal ibm server which use very old ssl protocols (ssl2, rc4 and other weak tools) for remote manage via ASMI , the modern browser has ssl3 and tls 1.1 disabled so cannot open a webpage "protected" using ssl2

Q: Why don't upgrade ASMI?

A: This server is discontinued since 10-15 years

Comment: Modern Browsers can still be configured to use older SSL revisions; worst case, you'd have to use an SSL stripping proxy. So, this whole dance is in vain (and it has plenty elements of a *Rube-Goldberg machine*). Just learn how to use a modern browser on your local machine and forward the network packets, like intended by the designers of a system that let you do administration over https.

Comment: Thanks I will consider this option, maybe in a isolated vm using ssh But just for learn I want to know why rsh is not working

Comment: No need for a VM. This is trivial to do on the very same machine you're currently using to access this website.

Comment: The machine is a vm

Comment: Yes, but the machine running the browser with which you access ASMI didn't have to be. That's the beauty of browsers. They run locally and connect to remote servers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, was a firewall problem. I don't know why but seems on Slackware rsh the port 1021/tcp needs to be open for rsh connections.
The line

```
xhost +192.168.0.33
rsh 192.168.0.33 DISPLAY=192.168.0.2:0 navigator
```

works fine

For a more secure environment I will try ssh + a browser configured for very old ssl and rc40 in a vm next time.

Comment: Yes rsh and rlogin were two different daemons running on different TCP ports (and `rsh host` without command actually called `rlogin`). With ssh, the two modes are handled by the same service.